# Clarification of different notions of spin structures

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}$I am confused about the equivalence of some various definitions of spin structures and I was hoping for some help clearing out the fog.  Let $B$ be a CW complex with oriented $n$-dimensional vector bundle $\xi$ and let $P \xi$ be the associated $\SO(n)$-principal bundle.  Let $\pi : \Spin(n) \to \SO(n)$ be the usual double cover.

**Definition 1:** A spin structure on $\xi$ is a $\Spin(n)$-principal bundle $P$ over $B$ together with an isomorphism of $\SO(n)$-principal bundles $\gamma : P \times_{\Spin(n)} \SO(n) \to P \xi$.  Two spin structures $(P_1, \gamma_1)$ and $(P_2, \gamma_2)$ are equivalent if there is a homeomorphism $f: P_1 \to P_2$ such that the induced homeomorphism $P_1 \times_{\Spin(n)} \SO(n) \to P_2 \times_{\Spin(n)} \SO(n)$ when post-composed with $\gamma_2$ gives $\gamma_1$.

**Definition 2:** A spin structure on $\xi$ is a $\Spin(n)$-principal bundle $P$ over $B$, together with a map $f : P \to P\xi$ which commutes with the projections to $B$ such that the following commutes:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
P \times \Spin(n) @>>\text{translation}> P\\
@V f \times \pi V V @VV f V\\
P \times \SO(n) @>> \text{translation}> P \xi
\end{CD}
We call two spin structures $(P_1, f_1)$ and $(P_2, f_2)$ equivalent if there is a homeomorphism $g : P_1 \to P_2$ with $f_1 = f_2 \circ g$.

**Definition 3:** For $n \geq 2$, a spin structure on $\xi$ is a class $\sigma \in H^1(P\xi; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ that restricts to a nonzero element in the fiber.  For $n=1$, a spin structure is just an element of $H^1(P\xi; \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$.  Two spin structures are equivalent if they are equal.

Why are these definitions equivalent?  There are other definitions that maybe come into the picture in making this clear, for example in terms of transition functions or maps to classifying spaces or trivializations of bundles over skeleta ….

Answer (score 1):

For the first two it's just a matter of expanding the definitions. For the third one I suggest reading Milnor's paper "Spin Structures on Manifolds".

Comment: I was looking at that paper of Milnor which prompted me to ask this actually.  With regards to (2) and (3) above he says "it is not difficult to show" that they are the same.  I didn't see how to do it.  Starting with the structure in (3), he tells us how to get a space which I believe is supposed to be the $Spin(n)$-bundle as in (2), namely the cohomology class gives a homomorphism $\pi_1(P\xi) \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and the kernel gives a cover of $P \xi$.  I was not sure how this is even a $Spin(n)$ bundle. I also do not know where the condition on the fiber comes in.